# Jenkins plugin : How to deactivate job save button when FormValidation.error() is sent?

Tags: java, validation, jenkins, plugins

In my own plugin Jenkins, I have mandatory fields to execute it. I use FormValidation (see code). But if I have a FormValidation.error(...), user can save the job. And the /configSubmit throw a exception.

```
private FormValidation mandatoryFieldIsValid(String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
        return FormValidation.error(ErrorMessageConstants.MANDATORY_FIELD_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return FormValidation.ok();
}
```

I expect that the save be impossible, to avoid a error screen with stackTrace of my InvalidArgumentException.

Thanks for your help.